# Specs2: Set number of per Spec parallel executions

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, specs2

How can I limit the number of tests that are executed in parallel per Spec?

A bit of Background: I know we can limit number of parallel Executions of Test Tasks within sbt, number of executors for specs, but it still can happen that one Spec has dozens of tests in itself.

From local tests it looks like it is related to the number of cores available. Which makes sense in general, however, as we are building on docker and machines can easily have 32 cores but share these with a few other builds. It looks like it can in the worst case execute an insane amount of parallel tests which results in random timeouts and failures.

A sample is at https://github.com/elm-/specs2-parallel-test.

Comment: Have you tried the `threadsNb` argument? https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Arguments

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. It works on the latest version of specs although, I can't get it to work on the 2.4.17 version of spec, although it is already in the documentation back then. I have a test project at https://github.com/elm-/specs2-parallel-test

Comment: However the sbt Task keys don't seem to work to limit the global parallel execution, but that's a 2nd problem =), thanks a lot, please create it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Also figured out the other one, I had to limit the global tasks.